# How can I combine two onclient click for javascripts in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I need to do two functions when I click the button  .The code I written is

```
           lnkBtn_mail.OnClientClick = imgBtn_mail.OnClientClick = "javascript:NewEmailMessageWindow(" + invoice.Id + ", " + FindPage.ToString().ToLower() + ");return false;";        
           lnkBtn_mail.OnClientClick = imgBtn_mail.OnClientClick = "return DisableButtons(true);";
```

The problem is always below one is executing.SO How can I call these actions at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them in one onclientclick:

```
imgBtn_mail.OnClientClick = 
    String.Format(
      "javascript:DisableButtons(true); NewEmailMessageWindow({0}, {1});return false;",
      invoice.Id, 
      FindPage.ToString().ToLower()
      );
```